# getting a method object for a class with compile time checking (in java)

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to get a Method object similar to this:

```
Method myMethod = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myDeclaredMethod",Arg1Class.class);
```

But!  I would like compile time checking of the existence of the method "myDeclaredMethod".  I don't actually need to dynamically choose the method, I just need a reference to it so I can pass it to another method... similar to the way C has function pointers.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void helloWorld() {
    printf("hello\n");
}

void runFunction( void (myfunc)() ) {
    myfunc();
}

int main() {
    runFunction(helloWorld);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice, if I mistype "helloWorld" in the call "runFunction(helloWorld)", I get a compile time error.  I want that same compile time error in Java, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that in Java.

However, the usual way to achieve this in Java is to define an interface that will declare only one method, the one you want to "pass as argument", and implement it in a class. Your class has to implement the method you are interested in. When you want to pass a "reference" to the method, you actually pass an instance of your interface. You can call your method on it.

An example might explain this:

```
interface Something {
    void doSomething();
}

class HelloWorld {
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

class Main {

    void runFunc(Something s) {
        s.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        runFunc(new HelloWorld());
    }

}
```

The problem is, if you want to call another method you need to create a new class implementing `Something`

Comment: Thanks for concisely answer the question and providing an alternative.   I wish there was another alternative, since interfaces in this context are not going to help me... I'm trying to (in the simplest possible way) call a method from the main thread and have it execute in another thread.  The best I have so far, is to use a queue and pass the method name as a string.  This is the best I have because there's about half a dozen methods I might call in the second thread and I don't want a 5 line solution that I have to repeat in half a dozen places in my code.

Comment: @Vivien I do not understand why `HelloWorld` does not implement `interface Something`, wouldn't that raise a compile error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Java: methods are not first-class citizens in Java.

But it is possible to do in Scala!

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer.  I would like to point out, though, that methods are not first-class citizens in C++ (that is, they are not objects), and compile time checking of method names as arguments can be done.  So that part of the answer is not a reason for the absences of compile time checking of method names as arguments to method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an annotations processor which using private APIs in the JDK check the the methods invoked via the reflection API and occassionally halt the compilation process.
This is detailed in [Compile-Time Checked Reflection API](http://dp4j.com/publications) as is done by dp4j.
If you use dp4j with @Reflect or [JUnit's @Test annotations](http://www.junit.org/node/591) you get the compile-time checking when you call the method 'normally', as in  `myDeclaredMethod(new Arg1Class())`

Comment: Sounds good.  I followed the link to compile time checked reflection api and there isn't a whole lot there.  Not sure what I was supposed to find, can you post a link to something with content?

Comment: check again - article published.